# Use dynamic dateRange to filter data and aggregate resulting dataframe by a dynamic selectInput

Tags: r, shiny, aggregate, shinydashboard, reactive

I'm developing a shinydashboard based on the following sample data frame:

```
Date     Year Month Week Wday Day Time  ActiveEnergy
2/1/2009 2009 2     5    Sun  1    0    55.36111
3/1/2009 2009 3     9    Sun  1    0    9.334444
4/1/2007 2007 4     14   Sun  1    0    41.27667
6/1/2008 2008 6     22   Sun  1    0    32.89833
7/1/2007 2007 7     27   Sun  1    0    27.11667
8/1/2010 2010 8     31   Sun  1    0    4.871111
```

On the sidebarMenu, under submenu "Historic", I want to display a **barplot** (ggplot) of ActiveEnergy consumed during the time range chosen by the user. This is done by selecting a `dateRangeInput` (start and end dates) in the calendar ("dateRange") included in the sidebarMenu.

In turn, I want the **x-axis** of the barplot to be the **selected time range** aggregated by the frequency chosen also dynamically from the "Select Time Interval" selectinput.

For that purpose, I created the `frequency` variable in the server, which translates the `input$TimeInterval` selected into the "by" variable I want to use in the "aggregate" function (e.g. "Weekly"="Wday").

However, I cannot manage to combine the reactive `input$dateRange`, `input$TimeInterval` and aggregate function together.

Any ideas on how to write this cascade filtering properly?

Below is my code for your reference:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  frequency <- observe({
    ifelse(input$TimeInterval=="Daily", "Hour",
           ifelse(input$TimeInterval=="Weekly", "Week",
                  ifelse(input$TimeInterval=="Monthly", "Month",
                         ifelse(input$TimeInterval=="Yearly", "Date"))))

  })

  filteredData <- reactive({
    data %>% filter(Date>=input$dateRange[1]  & Date<=input$dateRange[2])%>%
      select(frequency(), ActiveEnergy)
  })

  df<-reactive({
    freq<-paste(frequency())
    aggregate(filteredData(), filteredData()[[freq]] , FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(df(), aes(x=frequency(), y=ActiveEnergy)) +   geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill="steelblue")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: you should provide a reproducible example..and instead of `aes(x=frequency()..` it should be I think `aes_string(x=frequency()...`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call an `observer` like a reactive, it is not designed for this purpose as it produces **side-effects** rather than producing a reactive dataset. So your frequency should go in a `reactive`, which you can call elsewhere in your app.

You also dont need 2 reactives to produce the filtered / aggregated data, you can do that all in one, except you need both different datasets in different procedures.

And lastly, as @MLavoie already said, your `aes` should change to `aes_string`, as frequency will be a character value, which aes cannot interpret correctly. It will only show 1 bar.

Putting it all together you get:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

DateSeq = seq(as.Date("2012-1-1"), as.Date("2018-1-1"), "month")
data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:length(DateSeq),
  Date = DateSeq,
  Month = sample(1:12, length(DateSeq), T),
  Week = sample(1:10, length(DateSeq), T),
  Wday = sample("Sun", length(DateSeq), T),
  Day = sample(1:10, length(DateSeq), T),
  ActiveEnergy = runif(length(DateSeq), min = 2, 7000)
)




ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("TimeInterval", label = "time", choices = c("Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Yearly")),
  dateRangeInput("dateRange", "Date Select", format = "yyyy-mm-dd", start=min(DateSeq), end=max(DateSeq)),
  plotOutput("plot1")
)



server <- function(input, output) {

  frequency <- reactive({
    ifelse(input$TimeInterval=="Daily", "Day",
           ifelse(input$TimeInterval=="Weekly", "Week",
                  ifelse(input$TimeInterval=="Monthly", "Month",
                         ifelse(input$TimeInterval=="Yearly", "Date"))))
  })

  df <- reactive({
    data %>% 
      filter(Date >= input$dateRange[1]  & Date <= input$dateRange[2]) %>%
      group_by_(frequency()) %>%
      summarise(mean_active = mean(ActiveEnergy))
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = df(), aes_string(x = frequency(), y = "mean_active", 
                                   group = factor(frequency()))) +
      geom_bar(aes_string(frequency(), "mean_active"), 
               stat = "identity", fill="steelblue")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```